# How show I handle a 301 redirect from an existing page to another page in my index.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, http-status-code-301

Hi everyone and happy friday! Im just trying to find out what is the best way to handle a 301 redirect in node from an existing file to another file. Lets say I have a file that exists called /contact

```
router.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
  res.render('contact');
});
```

If I want to redirect users from that file onto a new route on wordpress, which is `/to/contact` should I do this?

```
router.get('/to/contact', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect(301).('contact');
});
```

I tried doing research on this but not sure what to do for a explicit redirect like here. Its a bit confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the two routes confused:

```js
router.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect(301, '/to/contact');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, it is not redirecting to the new route